# Windows 11 Some Keyboard shortcuts don't work

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11

I have installed by corporate IT Windows 11 Enterprise; now at least two shortcuts I use regularly don't function.

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd>/<kbd>RIGHT</kbd> are supposed to move the active window from one monitor to the other (in a two-monitor extended desktop config). Right now nothing at all happens.  Other shortcuts, such as <kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> to minimize a window, do work.

Is there a registry fix or a 3rd-party tool I can use to restore these shortcut combos?